# Ingres DB error E_PS055B CREATE PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, ingres

```
E_PS055B CREATE PROCEDURE: You may not create database procedure
    'proc_name'
    because database procedure 'proc_2' invoked by it is dormant.
    Any database procedure attempting to invoke a dormant
    database procedure is itself dormant, and it is illegal
    to create dormant database procedures.
```

I get this error when was trying to create procedure, could you please explain me what does it  mean, cant find any information on it

DB Ingres version 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Ingres documentation:

> The DROP PROCEDURE statement removes a database procedure definition from the database. Sessions that are executing the procedure are allowed to complete before the procedure's query plan is removed from memory.
>   If a procedure that is executed from another procedure is removed, the
>   calling procedure is retained but marked dormant, and cannot be executed
>   until the called procedure is restored.

In summary, proc_2 calls a procedure which has been dropped. This means proc_2 will be marked as dormant (as it cannot run) until such time as the dropped procedure is replaced. Any procedures which call proc_2 will also be marked as dormant. You will need to work out which procedure that proc_2 needs has been dropped and recreate it before you can create your new procedure.